# Merge two git repositories with different content and same branches names

Tags: git, merge, branch

I have two repositories with different content, i want to merge in one repository without loosing history and branches names:

Repo1: ( branches: A, B)

Repo2:( branches: A, B)

i wish to end with:

FinalRepo: (branches: A, B)
\Folder1 (with all content of Repo1)
\Folder2 (with all content of Repo2)

Comment: what do you mean with "all content of Repo X"? a repo holds branches, a branch holds directories and files. Anyway.... the fact that you have two repos with branches that have the same name doesn't matter. You can still fool around with them by saying: repoA/branchA, repoA/branchB, repoB/branchA, repoB/branchB. Maybe using merge --subtree strategy could help you _somewhat_ to reach your wishes.

Comment: I think the real question is going to be what the combined history should look like. If you're ok with the idea that *new* commits (starting from ones you create as you build the new repo) have the combined tree, while *old* commits have either "the new content" or "the old content", then it's not very hard at all. If you want to construct a history as though the two had always coexisted, that's much more difficult.